# Expiration certificate iPhone "in house" enterprise deployment

Tags: iphone, deployment, enterprise, certificate

Let's admit that I deployed an app on 100 iPhones, using the apple "in-house" deployment of the enterprise program. All of them will be connected to the internet. What will happen at the expiration of the distribution certificate ? All my employee will need to download the app again, signed with the new certificate ?
Or renewing the certificate will simply allow users to continue using it without downloading it again ?

Thank you very much for your answer...

Answer (score 2):

As documented in [Distributing Enterprise Apps for iOS 4 Devices](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009979-CH1-SW16) the App will refuse to work if the certificate expires. You'll need to rebuild your app with new certificate and re-distribute, e.g. "over the air".

Comment: How come I can delete the enterprise certificate on the device, and the app then continues working?

Comment: Caching. Restart device and the app shouldn't start. The caching of certs is documented by apple.